# Text input onChange in Chrome gives Uncaught NotFoundError

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have boiled my problem down to this small example:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Chrome test</title>
<script>
onload=function() {
  updateTagsList();
}
function updateTagsList() {
  var iel=document.getElementById("rftags");
  iel.innerHTML = '<input type="text" onChange="rfTagChanged()">';
}
function rfTagChanged() {
  console.log('rfTagChanged called - before calling updateTagsList');
  //debugger;
  updateTagsList();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class=inputarea id=rftags></div>
</body>
```

The problem materializes itself in that I get the error:

```
Uncaught NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.
```

on the line where I do iel.innerHTML = ... and I only get this error if I do "Enter" (CR or what to call it...) after filling in the text item. If I only click somewhere after I change the text, no error occurs, but the change-message is called and the update method called - as expected.

After some investigation, e.g. stopping with the debugger at the indicated location, I find that Chrome calls the rfTagChanged-method two times, ones as expected due to me typing on the keyboard and leaving the text item and then ones more from the updateTagsList method. And the error occurs on the second call to updateTagsList(). (Probably due to the DOM being in a "limbo" state as it is in the middle of an update?)

In e.g. FireFox the second change call does not occur, and in Chrome the second call only occur when adding "Enter" after typing text.

I have also tried adding an id to the new object and making it a different id each time - in the hope that the change would not be triggered when the elements added had different id's - but I still get the same error, ie a second call to changed.

Calling updateTagsList directly, ie onChange="updateTagsList()", gives the same error.

Is this a (know) bug or a feature of Chrome? (running latest Version 31.0.1650.63 m)

Any suggestions for workarounds?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Reset the input whenever a user types something?

Comment: You're replacing the whole input element while the user is trying to type into it. The behavior sounds like a bug in Chrome, but what you're doing seems perverse.

Comment: @Barmar, why the bug? It's pretty consistent to report "not found" error about element which was replaced with another one.

Comment: How should I know why Chrome has a bug? Like you said, it seems to get confused because you're pulling the rug out from under it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.I update the input area with new items as the user adds them.

Comment: Fingertrouble sorry. What I meant to say:Sorry for the late reply. I update an area on the screen with new items as the user adds them and add a new empty item at the end. The above code is a stripped down version. I update the input area with new items as the user adds them, however NOT while they are typing, but as they are finished, either by clicking outside the text input or hitting Enter. It works as I intend in FireFox and it works as intended when I just click outside the text field and don't type Enter.

Comment: Also: I run the same code weather I type Enter og just click outside the input field. Its just when I type enter that I get a new/extra call to changed as a result of my JavaScript code "iel.innerHTML = ..". And in FireFox I don't get this extra changed call.